# laravel carbon cannot show default promotion

Tags: php, laravel

I am using `laravel calendar` with [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) to show a daily promotion image.

I set the `image` in the calendar and it shows on the homepage. This part I am happy with.

The issue is if there is no promotion image set in the database, it is not showing a default image `/image/promotion.jpg`.

This is my controller code:

```
$setting = PromotionSetting::where('start_date', '<=', Carbon::now())->where('end_date', '>=', Carbon::now())->where('business_id', $business->id)->first();
    $promotion = BusinessPromotion::find($setting->promotion_id);
```

This is the code on the homepage:

```
<div class="business_promotion text-center mt-3">
                    @if(isset($promotion))
                        <img src="{{ $promotion->path }}" width="350px" class="promotion-img">
                    @else
                        <img src="/images/promotion.jpg" width="350px" class="promotion-img">
                    @endif
                </div>
```

Hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the $promotion->path image in isset()

```
<div class="business_promotion text-center mt-3">
                @if(isset($promotion->path))
                    <img src="{{ $promotion->path }}" width="350px" class="promotion-img">
                @else
                    <img src="/images/promotion.jpg" width="350px" class="promotion-img">
                @endif
            </div>
```

Comment: that'll throw a warning if $promotion isn't an object

Comment: then use $promotion['path']

Comment: Then it'll throw a warning if it isn't an array either.

Comment: I think its returning multiple objects you can check it by dd($promotion) and if its a multiple collection then you should use foreach and the try to access $promotion

Comment: It does throw the warning:  Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: image path is stored in a table which holds the path URL and the business ID

Comment: can you send image of dd($promotion); so i can help you

Answer (score 0):

You ask if `isset()`. It *is* set. It just happens to be null (probably).

Best changing the check to something like:

```
 @if(!is_null($promotion) && isset($promotion->path))
```

If that still doesn't work, you can force it null if it doesn't find the promotion like this:

```
$promotion = BusinessPromotion::find($setting->promotion_id) ?: null;
```

Then it should work. Let me know how you get on!

Comment: what happened?? I see the warning i mentioned in the other guy's answer was correct.

Comment: Still get warning: Trying to get property of non-object. got the warning before making any mentioned changes also

Comment: There is a separate table for the business promotion which just contains "business_id" and "path" (path storing the image path url.

Comment: Is it possible that `$setting` is also not being found? Which line is the error from, figure out which piece of code, it's one of those variables!!

Comment: It happens on this line:  $promotion = BusinessPromotion::find($setting->promotion_id); but if the image is set on the day in the calendar it shows the image fine, but if not set it throws the error

Comment: ok so try a `var_dump($setting); exit;` just befor it. What do you get?

Comment: It dumps all the $setting and show content from the database. think ive made it to hard using the calendar. do you know if it is possible to show a simple image per day? like have a monday - sunday image settings so every monday will show image 1, tuesday will be image 2 etc etc

Comment: so i found this issue i just dont know how to fix it. issue is this line: $promotion = BusinessPromotion::find($setting->promotion_id); it cannot find the promotion_id in the database tables because it does not exist unless i set a promotion image for the day. not sure how to get it to ignore and set default image if does not exist

Comment: you need to adjust your entity or db table, get it to allow null for that field